# Webview.reload in background Xcode 8.2 swift 3

Tags: ios

Happy new year to all.

Is it possible to make a `uiwebview.reload` if my app is running in background? I have a Timer with interval 20 seconds an random number 0-N + function that make `number = number + 20`. If number > random number then `webview.reload`. This works good on iOS 10.2 in simulator i press home button and lock. But it will not working on my device iPhone 6 iOS 10.2. Is it possible to make `webview.reloading` in background? Sorry my English is not good. 
In my project settings capability background is ON and I check background fetch

Answer (score 0):

If you know background fetch, this is hard to debug on a device because you're not guaranteed it is called in the amount of time you specify.

setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval means that it is not called in an interval which is smaller than the value you specified. But there's no setMaximumBackgroundFetchInterval. So if iOS decides to call your app just once a day or even just once a week. It won't be called more often regardless your minimumBackgroundFetchInterval. AFAIK iOS decides when to call performFetchWithCompletionHandler measured by the pattern when and how often the users start's the app.

Comment: And if I will update every max 10 minutes? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you write same code to set fetch interval? And I will call my app every 0-10 minutes. The system send all apps down every 3 minutes if I make fetch interval 170 seconds? Will this working?

Comment: Hi  Can somebody tell if it is possible to make a webview.reloadind if my app is running in background?